# how to copy android c2dm message to android clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard, android-c2dm

i have made it to notify me(via `NotificationManager`) for every c2dm message i get in my app.

Can i copy that message to android clipboard???
If yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ClipboardManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) to put things on the clipboard. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/ClipIP) demonstrating the use of `ClipboardManager`. Your `BroadcastReceiver` for C2DM will need to determine what part of the message goes into the clipboard and use `ClipboardManager` to accomplish that.